# Range row number reference from another cell in Excel

Tags: excel

[image]

Edited: So I made the question more complicated. If I would like to do a 'what if ' analysis which requires to be able to refer the last row to sum from another cell to the sumif formula. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the row numbers from your formula and use the entire columns:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,">4",B:B)
```

The beauty is that `SUMIF` will disregard non-nmeric rows anyway.

To sum up and stop at a certiain row, you can use `SUMIFS` with `ROW`:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">4",C:C,"<" & D2)
```

Where `D2` holds the row number using the formula `=ROW(<CELL>)`, i.e: `=ROW(A2)` in cell `C2`:

[image]

Comment: But what if I also have numbers above the label week?

Comment: @Coldcode it will still work. It will diregard the 1st row.

Comment: @Coldcode I see you edited your question. Let me explaing - my answer will still work, it will disregard non-number rows.

Comment: My point is that is there any method that i can actually reference the cell to the range because in this simple example that will work but if I have a more complicated situation where I want exact ranges. The formula can be other than the sumif.

Comment: @Coldcode That't not a right way to work with Excel. You don't "reference" the last row. All formulas should be applied on the entire columns. What other formulas for example?

Comment: I edited the post and made the question more complicated which requires the referencing.

Comment: So there is no formula that can reference directly from another cell?

Comment: @Coldcode No, you would have to do concatination with `&` like I did. Anyway, the answer I provided answers exactly what you need. I have to admit it took me a while. If you have another need post it as a new question and ping me here.

Comment: @Coldcode I voted up your question since it's very good and does not exist on SO, and hardly on the internet.